# VSCode does not ignore node_modules on suggestions

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, node-modules, intellisense

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3cx4.png) [VSCode settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRJXx.png)

If I delete node_modules it works perfectly. The problem is that it causes a big delay on suggestions.

Even if you disable suggestions, I think the intellisense its still working on the background searching through node_modules.

That's it, the switching to Neovim is imminent...

Answer (score 1):

Use `**/node_modules": true`. Including the `**` at the beginning covers the search term in any folders or sub folders.

Comment: Where. What file?

Comment: Within VSCode, go to File > Preferences > Settings. Then pick the Workspace tab, filter the settings by searching for ‘Search’ and add the pattern in ‘Search: Exclude’.